# Subset a JSON Object with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, select

I have a MySQL database and one of the tables is called 'my_table'.  In this table, one of the columns is called 'my_json_column' and this column is stored as a JSON object in MySQL.  The JSON object has about 17 key:value pairs (see below).  I simply want to return a "slimmed-down" JSON Object from a MySQL query that returns 4 of the 17 fields.

I have tried many different MySQL queries, see below, but I can't seem to get a returned subset JSON Object.  I am sure it is simple, but I have been unsuccessful.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    json_extract(my_json_column, '$.X'),
    json_extract(my_json_column, '$.Y'),
    json_extract(my_json_column, '$.KB'),
    json_extract(my_json_column, '$.Name')
FROM my_table;
```

yields:

```
5990.510000  90313.550000   5990.510000    "Operator 1"
```

I want to get this result instead (a returned JSON Object) with key value pairs:

```
[ { X: 5990.510000, Y: 90313.550, KB: 2105, Name: "Well 1" } ]
```

Sample data:

```
{
    "Comment" : "No Comment",
    "Country" : "USA",
    "County" : "County 1",
    "Field" : "Field 1",
    "GroundElevation" : "5400",
    "Identifier" : "11435358700000",
    "Interpreter" : "Interpreter 1",
    "KB" : 2105,
    "Name" : "Well 1",
    "Operator" : "Operator 1",
    "Owner" : "me",
    "SpudDate" : "NA",
    "State" : "MI",
    "Status" : "ACTIVE",
    "TotalDepth" : 5678,
    "X" : 5990.510000,
    "Y" : 90313.550    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One wonders why you are using JSON at all. Why not just have a normal table with normal columns instead of the fields of your JSON object? Then you would just use `SELECT X, Y, KB, Name FROM my_table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object), available since MySQL 5.6:

> Evaluates a (possibly empty) list of key-value pairs and returns a JSON object containing those pairs

```
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'X', json_extract(my_json_column, '$.X'),
        'Y', json_extract(my_json_column, '$.Y'),
        'KB', json_extract(my_json_column, '$.KB'),
        'Name', json_extract(my_json_column, '$.Name')
    ) my_new_json
FROM my_table;
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qLESvEAjcwX7gtXn49TUF/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| my_new_json                                                 |
| ----------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"X": 5990.51, "Y": 90313.55, "KB": 2105, "Name": "Well 1"} |
```

Comment: Wow!  A million thank yous.  JSON_OBJECT is it!  Thanks again for your real-time response.